# Is it possible to update component variables from within Svelte action?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, sveltekit, svelte-component

Can actions update component variables? For example, in the `App.svelte` below is it possible to update values of `disabled` and `errors`?

```
<script>
  import { form } from './use-form'

  let disabled
  let errors = {}

  const submit = e => {
    const formData = new FormData(e.target)

    const data = {}
    for (let field of formData) {
      const [key, value] = field
      data[key] = value
    }
    console.log(data)
    e.target.reset()
  }
</script>

<form on:submit|preventDefault={submit} use:form={[disabled, errors]}>
  <input name="email" type="email" required />
  {#if errors && errors.email} <p>{errors.email}</p>{/if}
  <input name="password" type="text" minlength="8" required />
  {#if errors && errors.password} <p>{errors.password}</p>{/if}
  <hr />
  <button formnovalidate disabled={!disabled}>submit</button>
</form>
```

Here's the `use-form` action:

```js
export const form = (node, [disabled, errors]) => {
  let inputs = node.querySelectorAll('input:invalid')

  const handleBlur = event => {
    ;[...inputs].forEach(e => {
      if (e.value.length === 0) {
        return
      } else {
        errors[e.name] = e.validationMessage
      }
    })

    disabled = node.checkValidity()
  }

  const handleInput = event => {
    ;[...inputs].forEach(e => {
      if (e.value.length === 0) {
        return
      } else {
        errors[e.name] = e.validationMessage
      }
    })

    disabled = node.checkValidity()
  }

  document.addEventListener('blur', handleBlur, true)
  document.addEventListener('input', handleInput, true)

  return {
    update: (disabled, errors) => {
      return disabled, errors
    },
    destroy: () => {
      document.removeEventListener('blur', handleBlur, true)
      document.removeEventListener('input', handleInput, true)
    },
  }
}
```

To better illustrate what I'm trying to achieve [here's](https://svelte.dev/repl/2e3434fe65174331b24179be87d4fe6a?version=3.24.1) a repel with a crude working solution albeit all is sandwiched in one file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work because Svelte does not know that they are updated. What you can do is either

- add events to the action and do the reassignment inside callbacks of the component: `use:form={{onDisabled: d => disabled = d, ...}}` (inside the action call `onDisabled(node.checkValidity())`)
- use stores instead because Svelte will notice when these are updated: `let disabled = writable(false); ...` (inside the action do `disabled.set(node.checkValidity())`)

Comment: I tried to do it with store (https://svelte.dev/repl/b452e7006bfb42759207fd8ed7aa708d?version=3.46.3) but it only works the first time round. Any further attempts won't show errors from the password input. Also, could you elaborate not the first method (events)? I'm not quite getting what you mean.

Comment: Your example is wrong, `update` is not doing what you think it does. `update` of an action is called when its inputs change. You need to call `disabled.set`/`errors.set` inside your input/blur callbacks.